# How to transform a truth table into a proof?

Tags: proof-writing

So here is my problem,  I am asked to prove that P $\leftrightarrow$ (Q $\leftrightarrow$ R) is equal to (P $\leftrightarrow$ Q) $\leftrightarrow$ R, pretty straight forward. So I made this truth table to prove it, and the truth values match up perfectly so this proves that they are true. Here is the truth table.

[Image of the truth table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lSjf4.jpg)

I know the truth table is accurate , but how can I turn this into a proof? They usually start with assume P is true etc.. but I legitmately need an example of transforming this table into that.

Comment: To show two statements A and B are equal, you can (additinally) show A iff B is a tautology, i.e.  Construct a final column [P iff (Q iff R)] iff [(P iff Q) iff R] and all the values must be T. This shows that regardless of the individual outcomes, the overall outcome will always be the same.

Comment: Are you expected to give a formal proof using a specific set of inference rules? Or is this to be proven informally? In the latter case, showing that their truth tables are identical suffices.

Comment: Yeah he wants a formal proof.. as in like words. I just don't get how to do it... Like I understand the truth table.